# Create Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have a function that is currently echoing image urls..

```
<?php
    $media = get_attached_media( 'image' );
        foreach ($media as $medias)
            {
                echo $medias->guid;
            }
?>
```

Which gives me the following output...

```
www.example.com/image1.jpg
www.example.com/image2.jpg
www.example.com/image3.jpg
www.example.com/image4.jpg
```

I am trying to put this data into a multi-dimensional array in a function instead that looks like this...

```
<?php
$images = serialize( array(
    'docs' => array(
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image1.jpg' ),
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image2.jpg' ),
    ) )
);

print_r( $images );

?>
```

I have read up on array_push, is this what I should be using or is it simpler than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `$docs[]` operator/shorthand:

```
<?php
    $docs = array();
    $media = get_attached_media('image');
    foreach($media as $medias) {
        $docs[] = $medias->guid;
    }
    $images = seralize(array('docs' => $docs));
    print_r($images);
?>
```

It's just short hand for `array_push` see the php.net docs:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Cheers!